# Google Distance Map with Shortest Path from given address/Lat,Lng and customise marker, One is default pick current location and one is customise

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a issue with google distance map, we have multiple locations and i want to drew map from my current location to nearest address from given multiple address and i have already created and its working fine, but i have a issue with map marker, by default its return marker point address but i want current location return default current position address and i want to customise only destination marker, when i use "suppressMarkers: true" destination marker customisation working but current position marker not return default current location, and when i use "suppressMarkers: false" both marker return default address/locations.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map,
        currentPosition,
        directionsDisplay, 
        directionsService,
        destinationLatitude = 67.38,
        destinationLongitude = -56.11;

    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        getLocation();
    });

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }
    function getPosition(position) {
        localStorage.setItem("current_latitude", position.coords.latitude);
        localStorage.setItem("current_longitude", position.coords.longitude);
        locSuccess(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    }

    function initializeMapAndCalculateRoute(lat, lon)
    {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: currentPosition,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            var currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: currentPosition,
            map: map,
            title: "My Location"
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent("Current position: latitude: " + lat +" longitude: " + lon);
            infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
        });
        calculateRoute(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
    }


    function locSuccess(latitude,longitude) {
        initializeMapAndCalculateRoute(latitude,longitude);
    }

    function calculateRoute(targetLat, targetLon) {

        var targetDestination =  new google.maps.LatLng(targetLat, targetLon);
        if (currentPosition != '' && targetDestination != '') {

            var request = {
                origin: currentPosition, 
                destination: targetDestination,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode["DRIVING"]
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                    $("#outputs").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#outputs").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#outputs").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our understanding, you should use "geocode" for the current formatted address.

If you will use "suppressMarkers: true", in that case, you have to set the marker manually. Use have no issue with destination marker customization but the issue with only starting/origin marker.

So you should customize the destination marker accordingly and by using geocode get the current location formated_address and set it within your origin marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, "click", function() 
{
        var point = currentPositionMarker.getPosition();
        map.panTo(point);
        MapGeocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': currentPositionMarker.getPosition()
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
            }
        });
});
```

Full Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Google maps</title>
    <style>
        .subheading,.sidelinks,.timify-widget-open-button{display:none!important}
        .map-container{box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #ccc;transition:300ms;display:flex;position:relative;overflow:hidden}
        .map-container input{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;width:0}
        .map-box{min-width:calc(100% - 200px);max-width:calc(100% - 200px);min-height:320px;height:calc(100vh - 340px);transition:300ms}
        .city-box{list-style-type:none;padding:10px 0;width:200px;height:100%;right:0;position:absolute;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;transition:300ms;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto}
        .city-box li{padding:12px 12px 12px 36px;cursor:pointer;background-image:url(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_greenA.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:25px auto;background-position:10px;transition:350ms}
        .city-box li.active{color:#fff;background-color:black!important}
        .city-box li:nth-child(even){background-color:#eee}
        .map-label{position:absolute;width:24px;height:60px;right:200px;top:calc(50% - 30px);background-color:#fff;box-shadow:-3px 0 3px #cccc;z-index:2;border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;cursor:pointer;transition:300ms;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}
        .map-label::before{content:'';width:10px;height:10px;margin-left:-2px;border-top:2px solid currentColor;border-right:2px solid currentColor;transform:rotate(45deg)}
        .map-container input:checked ~ .map-label{right:0}
        .map-container input:checked ~ .map-label::before{transform:rotate(225deg);margin-left:5px}
        .map-container input:checked ~ .map-box{width:100%;min-width:100%!important;max-width:100%!important}
        .map-container input:checked ~ .city-box{right:-200px}
        #floating-panel{position:absolute;top:10px;left:25%;z-index:5;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;border:1px solid #999;text-align:center;font-family:"Roboto","sans-serif";line-height:30px;padding-left:10px}
        .info_content{display:flex;width:100%;max-width:350px;align-items:center}
        .info_content .media-thumb img{max-width:100px;margin-right:10px}
        .info_content .content{display:inline-block}
        .info_content h3{margin:0 0 4px 0;font-size:15px}
        .info_content p{margin:0;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5}
        .scroller::-webkit-scrollbar{height:12px;width:5px;background:#333}
        .scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background:#969494;-webkit-border-radius:1ex;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)}
        .scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background:#333}
        .scroller{overflow-y:scroll;scrollbar-color:#333 #969494;scrollbar-width:thin!important}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid px-0 map-container">
    <div id="floating-panel">
        <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
        <select id="mode">
        <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
        <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
        <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
        <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="maptoggle">
    <label for="maptoggle" class="map-label maptogglemenu"></label>
    <div class="map-box" id="map_canvas"></div>

    <ul id="mybranches" class="city-box">
            <li class="active" data-lan="28.38" data-lon="77.12" data-title="Location Title" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Delhi, India</li>
            <li data-lan="12.120000" data-lon="76.680000" data-title="Location Title A" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Nanjangud, Mysore, Karnataka</li>
            <li data-lan="24.879999" data-lon="74.629997" data-title="Location Title B" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Chittorgarh, Rajasthan</li>
            <li data-lan="16.994444" data-lon="73.300003" data-title="Location Title C" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Ratnagiri, Maharashtra</li>
            <li data-lan="19.155001" data-lon="72.849998" data-title="Location Title D" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Goregaon, Mumbai, Maharashtra</li>
            <li data-lan="24.794500" data-lon="73.055000" data-title="Location Title E" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Pindwara, Rajasthan</li>
            <li data-lan="21.250000" data-lon="81.629997" data-title="Location Title F" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Raipur, Chhattisgarh</li>
            <li data-lan="16.166700" data-lon="74.833298" data-title="Location Title G" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Gokak, Karnataka</li>
            <li data-lan="19.076090" data-lon="72.877426" data-title="Location Title H" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Mumbai, Maharashtra</li>
            <li data-lan="14.167040" data-lon="75.040298" data-title="Location Title I" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Sagar, Karnataka</li>
            <li data-lan="26.540457" data-lon="88.719391" data-title="Location Title J" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Jalpaiguri, West Bengal</li>
            <li data-lan="24.633568" data-lon="87.849251" data-title="Location Title K" data-html="Web Site title | My location full Address" data-img="https://weneedwebsite.com/blog/assets/img/random-flags/images/67.jpg">Pakur, Jharkhand</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="results" style="display:none;">
    <div id="directions" class="scroller px-3" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_map_api_key_here&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&v=3"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map,
        currentPosition,
        targetPosition,
        targetMarker,
        infowindow,
        currentLatitude,
        currentLongitude,
        directionsDisplay, 
        directionsService,
        locationTitle,
        locationAddress,
        destinationLatitude = 49.4505682,
        destinationLongitude = 11.0702432;

    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("current_latitude")) {
            getLocation();
        }
        else{
            currentLatitude = localStorage.getItem("current_latitude");
            currentLongitude = localStorage.getItem("current_longitude");
            locSuccess(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        }
    });

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    function getPosition(position) {
        currentLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        currentLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
        localStorage.setItem("current_latitude", currentLatitude);
        localStorage.setItem("current_longitude", currentLongitude);
        locSuccess(currentLongitude,currentLongitude);
    }

    function locSuccess(currentLatitude,currentLongitude) { 

        var nearestLocation = null;
        var locations = [];

        jQuery('ul#mybranches li').each(function(){

            var location_lat = jQuery(this).attr('data-lan');
            var location_lng = jQuery(this).attr('data-lon');
            var location_title = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
            var location_address = jQuery(this).attr('data-html');
            var location_image = jQuery(this).attr('data-img');

            var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
            var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(location_lat, location_lng);
            var distance = calcDistance(p1, p2) * 1000;
            if ((distance * 1000) > 0) {
                if (nearestLocation === null || nearestLocation.distance > distance) {
                    nearestLocation = {distance: location_image, mylat: currentLatitude, mylng: currentLongitude, location_lat: location_lat, location_lng: location_lng, location_title: location_title, location_address: location_address, location_image: location_image };
                }
            }
        }); 
        
        var lat  = nearestLocation.location_lat;
        var long = nearestLocation.location_lng;
        var title    = nearestLocation.location_title;
        var address  = nearestLocation.location_address;
        var image  = nearestLocation.location_image;

        jQuery('#mybranches li[data-lan]').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('#mybranches li[data-title="'+title+'"]').addClass('active');

        initializeMapAndCalculateRoute(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,lat,long,title,address,image);
    }

    function initializeMapAndCalculateRoute(lat, lon, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, locationTitle, locationAddress,locationImage)
    {

        currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: currentPosition,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        MapGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var rendererOptions = {
            map: map,
            suppressMarkers: true
        };
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions); 
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: currentPosition,
            map: map,
            title: "Current position"
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ map: map });

        google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, "click", function() {
            var point = currentPositionMarker.getPosition();
            map.panTo(point);
            MapGeocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': currentPositionMarker.getPosition()
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
                }
            });
        });

        document.getElementById("mode").addEventListener("change", () => {
            calculateRoute(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, locationTitle, locationAddress,locationImage);
        });
        // calculate Route
        calculateRoute(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, locationTitle, locationAddress,locationImage);
    }

    function calculateRoute(targetLat, targetLon, locationTitle, locationAddress, locationImage) {

        const targetDestination =  new google.maps.LatLng(targetLat, targetLon);
        const selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value ? document.getElementById("mode").value : 'DRIVING';
        
        if (currentPosition != '' && targetDestination != '') {

            const request = {
            origin: currentPosition, 
            destination: targetDestination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
            };
            
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                createMarker(targetDestination, locationTitle, locationAddress, locationImage);
                
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                jQuery("#results").show();
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#results").hide();
            }
            });
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#results").hide();
        }
    }

    function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
        return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
    }

    function createMarker(latlng, label, html, image) {
        var contentString = '<div class="info_content">' +
        '<div class="media-thumb"><img src="'+image+'"/></div>' +
        '<div class="content">'+
            '<h3>'+label+'</h3>' +
            '<p>'+html+'</p>' +
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';
        targetMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_greenA.png',
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
        });
        targetMarker.myname = label;
        google.maps.event.addListener(targetMarker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, targetMarker);
        });
        return targetMarker;
    }

    function clearMarkers() {
        targetMarker.setMap(null);
    }
    
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'li[data-lan]', function () {
        if(!currentLatitude || !currentLongitude){
        currentLatitude = localStorage.getItem("current_latitude");
        currentLongitude = localStorage.getItem("current_longitude");
        }
        jQuery('li[data-lan]').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        destinationLatitude = jQuery(this).attr('data-lan');
        destinationLongitude = jQuery(this).attr('data-lon');
        locationTitle = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
        locationAddress = jQuery(this).attr('data-html');
        locationImage = jQuery(this).attr('data-img');
        clearMarkers();
        calculateRoute(destinationLatitude,destinationLongitude,locationTitle,locationAddress,locationImage);
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        if(localStorage.getItem('distancemapmenu') && localStorage.getItem('distancemapmenu') == 'checked'){
            jQuery('#maptoggle').prop("checked", true);
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.maptogglemenu', function(){
        if(jQuery('#maptoggle').is(':checked')){
            var value = '';
        }else{
            var value = 'checked';
        }
        localStorage.setItem('distancemapmenu', value);
    });
 </script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

[image]

As per screenshot Location, "Lucknow" is your default/origin location with default marker and location "Gurugram" is your customize(marker) location